# ACL mess after rsync on Windows 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, acl, icacls

The permissions in the ACL are not in the right order on some files and directories after having used rsync to synchronize directory trees. The stuff works well as it is on Windows 2003.

Can someone explain this in detail.

**What exactly changed regarding ACLs from Windows 2003 to 2008?**

We fixed the rights with `icalcs` afterwards. But this thing seems a bit weird. Maybe 2008 has some restrictions or more checks 2003 did not have.

Answer (score 0):

Initial reaction is rsync and Windows don't mix.  It would help to know the rsync command you used.

Comment: I have to check the script on monday and I can give you the info if you want to experiment around. I also think rsync is the culprit and does not support 2008, but why? what exactly changed in Windows from 2003 to 2008 that could explain that behaviour and it is not on all directories only some of them. We use rsync since a few years now for various tasks, it's the first time we see issues. That tool even handles the NTFS junctions well.